# Cluster algebra of finite type

Tags: representation-theory, quiver, cluster-algebra

It is proved in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208229) that a cluster algebra is of finite type if its Cartan counter part of the principal part of its seeds is a Cartan matrix of finite type. If the initial quiver of a cluster algebra is a Dynkin quiver, is it a cluster algebra of finite type? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For skew-symmetric cluster algebras, the matrix of a seed can be represented either by a skew-symmetric matrix or by a quiver.  The vertices of the quiver correspond to columns (or rows) of the matrix, and the number of arrows from $i$ to $j$ in the quiver is the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix, provided it is positive.  With this correspondence, saying that "Cartan counter part of the principal part of its seeds is a Cartan matrix of finite type" is exactly the same as saying that the quiver "is a Dynkin quiver".  According to the paper you linked to, one of the seeds satisfies this condition if and only if the cluster algebra is of finite type.

Comment: thank you very much. In [the lecture notes](https://www.msri.org/workshops/595/schedules/15561/documents/1438/assets/16934), on page 46, it is said that

A cluster algebra of finite type if and only if the mutable part of its quiver at some seed is an orientation of a simply-laced Dynkin diagram.

Why here it is required that the Dynkin diagrams are simply-laced?

Comment: @LJR Because if the matrix definig the cluster algebra is not skew-symmetric, then it cannot be represented by a quiver (but can be represented by a valued quiver).